AES Support on CardOS 5 smartcards
I have a CardOS 5 smartcard from ATOS, from the technical literature I can see that AES-CBC i supported for 128, 192 & 256 bit keys.
However I can't see any way to generate an AES key on the card to use AES encryption.
I've queried the supported mechanisms and AES_CBC is in the list but there is no AES_KEY_GEN support like there is for RSA.
So how would I use AES_CBC on this smartcard if I can't generate a key?

Isn't there a generic symmetric key mechanism present? AES keys just consist of random bits / bytes after all (I'd even recommend just generating random bytes for software implementations, but on smart cards usually you'd try and have additional protection for the keys).

Or maybe it requires you to upload / write the key to the card? For private keys it makes sense to generate them on card, but it is relatively uncommon that there is any use for symmetric keys on the card if you cannot export them from the card. So you might as well import them instead.

I assume you want to do that for computation of a session key. Note, that the standard command for generating session keys (typically the verbs negotiate or derive are used instead) is MUTUAL AUTHENTICATE. If you don't have access to the corresponding CardOS User's Manual (describing the variants without, with and with standardized session key derivation), you should consider signing an NDA to get one.
Using static keys is simpler. You create a key object with the appropriate algorithm/padding using PUT DATA_OCI and the chosen (e. g. random number) data.
